# osgeo available in QGIS, but not in mac command line interface

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

I am getting an error when I try to import osgeo from the python console on my mac (OS 10.13.6):

```
>>> import osgeo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

As far as I know, GDAL is installed properly because I can get it's version from the bash command line:

```
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19
```

In case my python version is relevant:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.0
```

I installed it when I installed QGIS and interestingly `import osgeo` is working just fine from the QGIS python console. Any tips how to get it to work in the plain interactive console in Terminal?

Comment: If is QGIS 2.18.x, you must use Python 2.7 and in the case of 3.x, Python 3.6. So, you are using another Python installed in your machine.

Comment: GDAL is indeed installed but have you installed the python libs for osgeo? Is there a folder in your python install site-packages named osgeo? Do you have more than one python install?

Comment: @aldo_tapia I am using QGIS 3, but I think the problem might indeed have to do with having multiple versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed GDAL with Homebrew:

- from osgeo4mac:

  - Python 2.x / QGIS 2.x: /usr/local/Cellar/gdal2-python/2.X.X/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
  - Python 3.x / QGIS 3.x: /usr/local/Cellar/gdal2-python/2.X.X/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
- from homebrew core:

  - Python 2.x / QGIS 2.x: /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.x.x/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  - Python 3.x / QGIS 3.x: /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.x.x/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Before running Python, just do

`EXPORT PYTHONPATH=_one_of_above_`

Comment: Thanks Denis, I couldn't remember how I installed GDAL but it appears that it wasn't with Homebrew (based on the directory where I found it). Adding to the python path was the correct solution though!

Answer (score 1):

The following solved it for me.

I found the location of the GDAL site-packages by typing `osgeo` in the python console in QGIS:

```
>>> osgeo
<module 'osgeo' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py'>
```

I read that the directory where your module lives has to be in your python path, and when I checked it wasn't there:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Python/2.7/site-packages/osgeo', '/Users/<my_user_name>', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.15.0/libexec/nose/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

So I added that path to my python path. For me that meant editing my ZSH profile (`vi ~/.zshrc`), but if you don't use ZSH you'll want to edit your bash profile or whatever you do use. In any case, I just added this line:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"` to my bash profile
```

Then I reloaded my profile (`source ~/.zshrc` or open a new shell), started the python console again, and it worked!